# Create text in <p> tag in depend on <select> tag, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

I want to create p tag with text(or something like that) after input tag, that inform user about value he/she type in this field, before this user select country in select tag.
For example:
User select USA: after input must appear "USD"
User select England: after input must appear "GBP"

And explain please why my code doesn't work, is it the right way?

JS:

```
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) 
{
     referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function createText() 
{
     var selectValue = document.getElementById("money").value;
     var CashInput = document.getElementById("cash");
     var temp = document.createElement("p");
     if (selectValue == "pound") 
     {
         var text = "GBP";
         temp.appendChild(text);
         insertAfter(CashInput, temp);
     }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select id="money" onchange="createText();">
    <option value="pound">England</option>
    <option value="doll">USA</option>
</select>

    <input id="cash">
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `.appendChild()` is for appending nodes, not strings of text. Instead, do `temp.appendChild(document.createTextNode("GBP"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an existing element and just changing it's innerText attribute. Here is a functioning example.

```js
function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) 
{
     referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function createText() 
{
     var selectValue = document.getElementById("money").value;
     var CashInput = document.getElementById("cash");
     if (selectValue == "pound") 
     {
         var text = "GBP";
     } else if (selectValue == "doll") {
         text = "USD";
     }
     document.getElementById("currency").innerText = text;
}
createText();
```

```html
<select id="money" onchange="createText();">
<option value="pound">England</option>
<option value="doll">USA</option>
</select>


<input id="cash">
<span id="currency"></span>
```

Comment: Yes it works if you click "Run Code Snippet" and toggle the "England/USA" dropdown the text updates.

Comment: Older versions of Firefox didn't support `.innerText`, but rather `.textContent`, so that may be why.

Comment: Make it right, when I change USA/England it have to create text after input right? Because it's don't:(

Comment: Ok, understand, I use firefox

Comment: Thank you, it's my lack of knowledge only